# OpenCL configuration settings

Tags: opencl, nvidia

I have a project which requires OpenCL. I have installed CUDA and OpenCL on my machine but when I 'make' my project the following error occurs:

> CL/cl.h: No such file or directory

I'm using windows7 and Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Make sure you have the path to your include files set as one of the ["Additional Include Directories"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w(v=vs.90).aspx) of your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error indicates that the compiler is not able to find the CL/cl.h header file. Find out where the OpenCL SDK you are using is installed and the directory that contains the OpenCL header files inside it.

On my computer for example, the Intel OpenCL SDK header files are in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\1.5\include\CL` And the NVIDIA OpenCL header files are in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.1\include\CL`

To compile with the Intel OpenCL SDK, I would add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\1.5\include` to the Visual Studio project. That is, add this path to Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories

Comment: Can we use nvcc compiler to compile .cl files?? Lets go eith the same question above. After linking all libraries, when we select compiler by right clicking on .cu file (in case of cuda), its CUDA C/C++. What it should be in case of .cl file??